# decode base64 encoded signatures to image in php

Tags: php, base64, decode, signature, wacom

We are using a wacom pad that convert signatures to base64 strings encoded and we store these in a database. After that i retrieve these encoded strings and decode them in php using base64_decode() and then try to convert this decoded string to an image.The result im getting is the following:

> �{�{|��;z�y�����N^~�N�ߏ��!��d�5uU%�#�sҲb@#���� �����8�=~���=�~����������=B��@�@��(`@}}�9�z�:t�������1�\TL<0�����w�P0�C�@B�$C�phXH@o�`�!@?}�� ("&P��qaqaA`"�D��{ ���ó����������$DXht� "B2bB2R�qa@"��G� �����Ֆ֖��QO�JG�z���������W_s�����������=�z�u������`�~>~���@�}����xzz�y� ."*6>J��1!�Рx`x����|�}  ��:40*( " /@ /����ogG�޾�������'W�� �#c�d���C�B�a��@�@�����Ο��@���o����0 @0`�!^��Ã��~    ��������������@�`` ��@E; ����~}����� (0_��@}�z���������p����� @$T�F�DBA��;����54��vwx�;��?@B����ǈɊJ� �GE��A��~���������$0@L\p|q��a РP@�Ͽ�����Oo������Aq�����qP�� �;�<�<����(8H,48@PTd`h`XL8,��˻����{�<�=ޟ?�@�a�b�C�d�EeE�#��@@�=����$X@PXlt|���phTD0(����O_o���@p��A`#��@��$!# ,H�0`P` ��??�@��D�F����B>8.( ��������'0�����@��"��@IA�&" (0���0�!1aQ�q�q�!00�>�}<;���{������������?��Q��B����F_�L��+-).1^����$��@"H�sgO�@x��%ɒg����<��N;��[���|9w���n�k՛88�Ë,������ �D ��+Z�9��� B8�"���B�,`"�L@�0 ��@�x��߀>kB L�Be�8`��A��?x��`�x<��N���� ~�@�$^8h�Ft4P�� |@o�p �9���?��?�^����=��P@�!}0yIP|8h���_>����>��ӳ^�t��V��xt���?��@aB ��� �'�����'�C� ��0p��7��~� �(8a@�?� 6pۧ.o�z�y���� &4�c�$F��L 8Hp��}���;�ٿg-�;�� a�����т�������g-{rf�r�0jQ^��9�kٻ]w����H�*P����}�����|���ƂK��JW��K�.d?�"=�_���A����G g A� ``Dp,a!c�@`?��ۗ �s�ɏ6]�o������.h�(G�Dh�4X�����ݬ=j׿�`��0�"H����r�Ȏ����n۳^��ٳo]z��!��&��B@��0@��� $ $@ 8(@?�y�ˎ���n;�����B"T��@���bd�� ��n;��ٷ������aX#7D8P@������]�o��AC  �F�0`�/����>}x���~~���@�� :� �a���b#��B�>{��ǟ9���>��N|xoݷ`;v�ßo??�H"��$߀��@v���￀~�����GKrd�� <`�"���{�P�E��F 00|�ۧ=땀�:� 3��&�@@@�@@�@O� ��Q��=?A� ������ݽ�����U;=>� ������������\�J:=* ����������������������������������������������ظ����]�^@BA ��������������0479  �������.31 � �����������   ��@�0dm�)}p����� ,�@X`4��8  ����������������~G����|���>�������~@�0�0.����:���$��@���`�( � ���p}�4�� '����������������_��������0� 0�� }�:@�`���?���@�����O��?��������|>���D|�����/�������*�����P @���"���<�}����~�?������?����4@.��5��`&` ��@�0h@D ,�:r��+�����~����w��������PA��<�@`@�p��p`�@@� @��*�����������߹�~�������?���@8 p8)����tA�4���$@:������*���o��>��������������@p�l��`��<���@2������~��������~�����_�����@F�`8P����~����*���������o������X �D�� s��h0� >�?����/����������`$x�d�@�E���:@� <�@�|���~O��d�������?�����@�����f A�4�pd���~���>���_o�����W�����p P��>r�l @( ��?����?���@ �� �@@��������0?���9o����� ����x���H���7������?��P��� �`A� '�������0��� *��H�D ��4�`d ��?`��ߟ���������@�@ P4�A���6@� @x ����5���������}߫��W����*�����������~�����y�=��'����|/��~���*�����)z� p�������?���������?���������P@H�\�p`� I  �@)� �� ;@�P��������/��~������Oq�~W�������P �h�pX��o��`A0 `T����?��/���g�����/����������@���8 ��8A%��!���0���?������>������@p�`��DA!�h�0� ����O���?���{�}����g����`` X ��8��L����������(������������@8�8�@@��@x �,�� 0��� < �� �P�����?��_k�^J���@` ��p~��@0� ��    �����0A_����@@�� ���~����>�����@<�B AH U�PB@�`�����������zO;���������O�����@\� `` ��A��P���9����.@P�L�*��}o������7�}���`��h A�2��0<�`���������?���G�������v���0x l��P�p�����O���8���~�����> ���P&@p 8����������������*8����g���G�}����w��*`x��h�{��h�X!`P���������������|��?H�`:�`1�AŰt�2����&� ���*���/��?*�}����/��*� ������@ H&��@l��@���� ������������o������������?�������?�`�_�@���@��L P&���X 8� �� ������?���������������}��� /�@�p� ����� ��� @P����_�~���?W���~_����?���o�����`��������?���@�?��@�� ?��̀ ��    t��A`)p� ��0��0$d0�`)p�p��P@!*�p���аP&��A`� A@���P�  ����{������7����� �  �@��?��?�����    � � �����������?������������ �����������~�� ��������juZ���@�b6�A��X*����P@0� @ �`������������@0�/��A������?������@�@�� ������?������������?����'������������?����@`� � ��?�O��?�������@ �� �������������@�����A�����?�?�_�?�@�P@������@������A�?�@@>� ����/���������@�C����?�� � @ ��� �������À9����������5� �Ϝ$�PO)¡@�8 y�|zz}N�U���P�0@�@�������g��p\�l���V}ó�֖7&�6�gC�uv��F�w2rs�V�FW'&�6S�u6W'f�6R6�s�b��sc�aU5ES�u5ER�Ss�"��#����Ss�5EQ�{��z@S�P�N�+��+� " />

And the code is:

```
$decoded = base64_decode($base64StringImg);
header("Content-type: image/GIF");
return'<img src="data:image/GIF;base64,"'.$decoded.'" />';
```

been fighting with this for hours, what can the problem be?

Comment: That means it's not base64 encoded

Comment: why you decode, when you send inlined image and point to browser that this is base64-encoded data? You need to send it as is (ofc if it is an image and properly encoded to base64 format).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deliver the signature image on browser. you don't need to decode it. just deliver base64 encoded string and browser will show it.
Check this code:

```
$path = '1.gif';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

echo $base64;

echo '<img src="'.$base64.'" />';
```